# Disable level log log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have errorAppender and infoAppender to separate in 2 log files.

That is working, but I need to log in info file only info information.

Example:
when I call logger.error("TEST ERROR"), I don't want this showing on info file.

is there any way to disable level logs?

**log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="errorAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/log/error.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="infoAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/log/success.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    </appender>

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="errorAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="infoAppender" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: You could use a [LevelRangeFilter](https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/levelrangefilter-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Fildor, it is working now using LevelRangeFilter

```
<appender name="infoAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/log/success.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="INFO" />
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
    </filter>
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
</appender>
```